# t-sql repeat row numbers within group

Tags: sql, sql-server, dense-rank

I need to create an ID for every time a name changes in the task history.
The rank needs to do restart **with each **task and step**.**

The closest I got to my goal is using the code below.

But it does not produce correct result for when a person appears again in the historical list of actions.

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY TaskName, Person)
```

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: What if there is more than one task?  Do you want the numbering to continue or start over?  What if the tasks are interleaved?

Comment: Gordon, the rank needs to restart at each new step, regardless of task. Your question helped me understand my problem a lot better!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lag()` to see where a person changes.  Then use a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when prev_person = person then 0 else 1 end) over
           (partition by task_name order by timestamp) as desired_output
from (select t.*,
             lag(person) over (partition by task_name order by timestamp) as prev_person
      from t
     ) t ;
```

Note:  I am interpreting your question as your wanting the numbers separately for each task ("every time a name changes in the task history").

EDIT:

Based on your comment:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when prev_person = person and prev_stop_name = step_name then 0 else 1 end) over
           (partition by task_name order by timestamp) as desired_output
from (select t.*,
             lag(person) over (partition by task_name order by timestamp) as prev_person,
             lag(step_name) over (partition by task_name order by timestamp) as prev_step_name
      from t
     ) t ;
```

Comment: Gordon, your answer worked for the original ill-worded edit of the question. I now know that it's either step OR name change that i need, but i know how to adapt your code. Thanks!